# How to get an empty Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation element?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

normaly I will use `return $this->belongsToMany(...)` to get elements wich are connected to the actuel element in a table.
But at the beginning my students won't have created the second table so the command above will fail.
Do you have any idea how to retun an empty element of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` to prevent the view to break?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation object but an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.

You can instantiate it like this:

`$empty_collection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;`

Comment: This will break in case of eager loading.